# Wso2 token expires

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Wso2 Identity Server v 5.1.0, with integrated LDAP disabled and using Readonly LDAP for authentication

when authenticating user with wso2 IS using /oauth2/token API, initially wso2 returns output as following

```
{
"access_token": "fa738bd8c50d4506cf2c3566ed86adb8",
  "refresh_token": "9b2d346cc05f827f4cab99bc9c90401a",
  "scope": "openid",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

when accessing API again in 1 seconds it provides expires as '3300',

So my question is why 300 deducted everytime when accessing API for first time ?

Comment: Did you see same behavior for other api calls again and again ? or just for 1st api call ? Can you show us your identity.xml configurations ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the value of identity.xml

```
<OAuth> --> <TimestampSkew>300</TimestampSkew>
```

by default value is 300. When calculating expiry time reduce time stamp skew also to put client in safe side (network delays...etc). You can change the value as required.

Comment: Is it in seconds?...10 minutes is hell lot of time. This is very bad, In existing implementation wso2 returns 3600 as expiry but internally it takes as (3600-timestampskew), This should be opposite. It should be implemented opposite way. Wso2 returns 3600 and internally should calculate as 3600+timestampskew. When client tries to refresh token he can actually refresh timestampskew seconds in advance !!!!

Comment: If you think 10min is much larger, you can use small number. For your concern about time stamp calculation please send a mail to dev@wso2.com.

Answer (score 1):

From [WSO2 docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Token+API#TokenAPI-Configuringthetokenexpirationtime):

**Configuring the token expiration time**

User access tokens have a fixed expiration time, which is set to 60 minutes by default. Before deploying the API Manager to users, extend the default expiration time by editing the `<AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>` element in `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/identity.xml`.

Also take the **time stamp skew** into account when configuring the expiration time. The time stamp skew is used to manage small time gaps in the system clocks of different servers. For example, let's say you have two Key Managers and you generate a token from the first one and authenticate with the other. If the second server's clock runs 300 seconds ahead, you can configure a 300s time stamp skew in the first server. When the first Key Manager generates a token (e.g., with the default life span, which is 3600 seconds), the time stamp skew is deducted from the token's life span. The new life span is 3300 seconds and the first server calls the second server after 3200 seconds.

You configure the time stamp skew using the `<TimestampSkew>` element in `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/identity.xml`.

**Tip:** Ideally, the time stamp skew should not be larger than the token's life span. We recommend you to set it to zero if the nodes in your cluster are synchronized. Also, note that when the API Gateway cache is enabled (it is enabled by default), even after a token expires, it will still be available in the cache for consumers until the cache expires in approximately 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

given that i understand your query, try
changing the value of `<TimestampSkew>300</TimestampSkew>` found in IS_HOME\repository\conf\identity\identity.xml to `<TimestampSkew>0</TimestampSkew>`